# import python relative path files in linux redhat

Tags: python, linux, redhat

```
.
├── another_dir
│   └── main.py
└── utils
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── config.py
    └── helper.py
```

```
$ vi main.py

    from utils import config
    from utils import helper
```

this is throwing no module utils error, how to do relative import of python files in linux

Comment: One way is `sys.path.append('..')`.  A better way is to extract the file's directory from `__file__`.

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks Tim, 
import sys >>
sys.path.append('/home/user/utils') >>
from utils import config

tried this but still ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'util'

Comment: `sys.path.append('/home/user/')` do not add the module folder, only it's parent. You can also do it when calling python by setting `PYTHONPATH=/home/user`

Comment: @zigarn thanks heaps! it worked with '`sys.path.append('/home/user/')`

Answer (score 0):

There is some ways. one of them is adding parent direction to path:

```
import path
import sys

# directory reach
directory = path.path(__file__).abspath()
  
# setting path
sys.path.append(directory.parent)
  
# importing
from utils import config
from utils import helper
```

or if you have madule you can easily use that with add .. before it :

```
# importing
from ..utils import config
from ..utils import helper
```